# Is it possible to intentionally limit bacteria's lifespan?

Tags: bacteriology, biotechnology

Say I have a species of bacteria. I want this species to only persist for a set number of generations, after which it simply stops reproducing. Is it possible to do this at all (with known genetic engineering techniques), and if so, how do you prevent bacteria from evolving against it?